# How to show Pop when load new page and show the ok button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following page to redirect the next page when success current page.

How to show the pop up when load the new page and click the ok pbutton it will move to next page.

How to achieve this?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {  //or  $(window).load(function(){ 
    $('#myModal').reveal($(this).data());
});

    </script>

           <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
                <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
                <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
                <inputbutton name=ok value="www.mpage.com"/>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery would probably be the quickest way to do this.

You can collect the form data and then send it to the server using the jQuery AJAX functions (NetTuts+ has an old, but still relevant tutorial on that [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59)), and then use a modal library (eg. [Remodal](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal)) to actually show the modal.

Comment: I'm anxiously waiting for a better solution from the person who downvoted this.

Comment: I have seen our code but m requirement is. I want to call one pop method instead o that weblink(input hidden tag)